# Trac vs. Redmine

Tags: project-management, trac, redmine

I'm working in research and my bioinformatics work group needs a project management software for keeping track of multiple projects (Linux environment). Originally, we planned for using TRAC but then I got aware of REDMINE. Moreover, I read in some earlier posts from 2008 and 2009 that many projects had switched to Redmine. Right now, I cannot find any up-to-date or reliable comparison between both systems and thus cannot wage which one is better (maybe both are equally good).

**My question:**

Does anyone of you have **recent** experience in one or even both of these systems and can point out some (big) advantages/disadavantages of either Redmine or Trac (or even both)?

**Requirements would be:**

- svn and/or dcvs (Git) support
- document management
- ticketing
- bug tracking
- wiki / internal blog (i.e., knowledge management)
- multiple project support
- installation should be as easy as possible
- there shouldn't be hundreds of plugins to be installed before getting a usable project management software up and running (base installation should have most features)

Thanks a lot for your time!
Cheers

Comment: Trac has no built-in support for many of the VCS that Redmine supports out of the box. Otherwise there are probably criteria like different Wiki syntax and so on. I found the installation of both relatively easy and straightforward. With Trac I had problems first time I tried setting up multiple projects and with Redmine once I had problems because of some prerequisites (that are not part of Redmine).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130466/trac-vs-redmine-vs-jira-vs-fogbugz-for-one-man-shop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366394/internal-bug-tracking-tickets-redmine-trac-or-jira

Comment: I think it is very constructive.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I use Redmine and ... i like it ;)

- svn and git works fine, it has more repos implemented (Darcs, Mercurial, Cvs, Bazaar, Filesystem ??? ), but haven't tried using them
- about installation - in my case auto installator on my hosting, so i can't say a thing, you should be able to find many tutorials
- ticketing / bug tracking - i think, for both RM and Trac it is main functionality, so too much to write about ;)
  you can configure roles, link users or groups with project, specifying role for each
  you can specify your own issue (ticket) type, for eg. bug, new idea, issue priorities
  you have gantt chart (you can specify deadline for each issue), you can link every ticket with version of your project ... many, many features here
- multiple project support - you can have multiple projects linked with one ( i mean the same ) or more repos
- document management / wiki / internal blog - havent used this feature, but yes, RM has something for doc management and wiki module
- 100's of plugin ... i have none and still there are too many config options :P

Comment: I've worked with both, and I would advise Redmine too : the basic feature are a lot less plugin dependent and the interface is better TMHO. Moreover many configurations of trac require you to edit config file whereas Redmine offers interface to do it which means : that it's usable by basic human beings not only by sysadmins.

Comment: Add : The only problem I had with Redmine is installing it since ubuntu package contains a very very old version. Read this for your setup : https://wiki.koumbit.net/RedmineConfiguration (it helped me a lot for the git plugin)

Comment: I would like to use Trac because its written Python instead of Ruby (I dont speak Ruby but Python and I want to make my own plugins) but the missing Multi-Project support is a No-Go for me. Make about 50 Trac environments, one for each project? No way. Even if I think Redmine has a few drawbacks Redmine is still the better solution if you have many projects.

Comment: @fnkr, you are wrong. Multi-Project is a stable Trac plugin you can install as add-on to a basic Trac installation. Look at http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SimpleMultiProjectPlugin.

Comment: @falkb I already know about that plugin, its mentioned in the Trac wiki. I haven't tried it because I haven't found info about the Wiki, Repos and Permissions on their page. Does it support a Wiki per Project? Does it support Repositorys per Project? And what about Permissions? This is very important for me. I have open source projects, private projects with an open bug tracker but private repo and completely private projects. Oh and open source project sometimes have issues that should only be viewable by team members.

Comment: @falkb Btw. their page says `Still an experimental version`. Doesn't sound like `stable` :)

Comment: @fnkr: I removed the sentence about "experimental", this was just forgotten. :)

Comment: Permission: you can restrict the projects to certain users. Repos and wiki per project is not supported. Does Redmine support that? Trac is just on top of source repos, so the repos are independent. You can completely restrict people from repos by using e.g. SVNs authentification system, independently managed from Trac's projects. And we restrict Trac's source browser and the wiki just on per-usergroups basis via the fine-grained permission system of Trac, actually no real need to chain that on projects.

Answer (score 73):

**I would favour Trac.** I've used Trac a long time over 7 years by now. I've also worked 3 years with Redmine. Latest versions I used in production were: Trac 1.0.1 and Redmine 2.2.3. But Redmine has some serious drawbacks over Trac:

1. **Installation** is not easy:

   1. You cannot use Debian/Ubuntu package system for production use

      - As configuration is not separated from application code, whenever you get package updates, they will overwrite your changes.
      - Debian had 5 security holes at the beginning of 2013 (January), where [some](http://www.debian.org/security/2013/dsa-2604) still unfixed in unstable and testing. Of course fixes in Debian stable is done, the package versions are so outdated in stable, that newer versions of Redmine will not work.
      - Redmine's dependencies are fixed, so new library versions might not work. This is the reason that you must configure your apt-get or aptitude not to upgrade certain dependencies.
   2. I advise you to install via `gem` and `bundler`. However, this was as easy as described on the homepage. But what I hate most about those software package management systems beside the systems package-management is, that you have to care for updates and all other stuff separately. Some people suggest [RVM](https://rvm.io/) providing virtual ruby environments, where you can have multiple Rails versions installed next to each other, which is not possible with apt-get. I don't feel good with this but at least it works.
2. **Administration** is not easy, considering making a backup: In Trac this is a one-liner, in Redmine, you have to backup: configuration, attached files and database content all separately. Additionally, often it is stated that Redmine supports multiple projects, so its easier to setup a new project and configuration is not duplicated. See below, there is an extra paragraph on multiple project support. Last but not least, whenever I administer a Trac project I love to edit PLAIN-TEXT configuration files. In Trac there is only **one** such file you need to look at: `trac.ini`.
3. **Configuration** is broken: E.g consider creating custom routes in Redmine, that show the start wiki page and not the project overview as first page. You will be recommended to edit Redmine's sources! That is very dangerous as next update will overwrite your configuration. So such kind of configuration was not really intended. But a good tool should separate configuration from application source code.
4. **Wiki features missing**: Some important wiki features are missing due to an unfixed bug related to a XSS vulnerability. (e.g. see textile wiki markup). So you will end up not able to place comments inside wiki pages, render images in custom size,...
5. **Missing Spam protection**: Yes there is an outdated reCaptach plugin, but it doesn't work anymore. Especially the fork also protecting the issue-pages. Compared to Trac which has a SpamFilter plugin which has [fantastic properties](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/SpamFilter) this is a no-go. No one wants to delete spam manually.

Many critical points have been made over time that made people say, Redmine is better. I doubt those:

1. **Multiproject support:** Of course Trac provides multiple projects, each having its own configuration!, and this is very *helpful*: Consider making one project closed source and one open source. For the closed source you will probably hide the Repository, but not for the open source project. this is not possible with Redmine. Furthermore, with Trac you can Backup the projects separately and of course you can separate them incase one of your 50 projects become popular so it will need an own server! Redmine cannot do this. Recently, a new plugin came up supporting multiple user projects in one Trac instance, look at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PluginList#MultipleProjects

   Beside that, there is a Project using Trac to build this feature: [Bloodhound](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound)
2. **Version Control System:** I think installing a plugin is not that hard, and for almost every VCS there is a plugin for Trac: Git, Perforce, Mercurial, Darcs, Monotone, Subversion, Bazaar. Furthermore I would favour a small core framework with plugins over a big framework with integrated support for Git, Mercurial, etc... Such an architecture is not modular. So putting VCS support to plugins is the way to do it. Not to integrate everything into the framework.
3. **Plugins:** I would argue Trac and Trac-Hacks have much more plugins than Redmine, so integration of Doxygen, Jenkins, Latex, BibTex, etc. is no problem!
4. **Timing and Estimation**: There are plugins for that in Trac too!
   All in all I don't understand the recent Trac-bashing, It's also written in a trendy interpreter language (python), it has almost the same functionality.

Redmine's installation process is not easy, but Trac installation became also more complex these days so manual database creation, etc. can't count as a drawback anymore.

Last but not least, both projects using a plugin system. The problem the user of such plugins often has is, they may be orphaned and not supporting the current framework. This happend to me more than a dozen times for Redmine, but also sometimes for Trac. But my very subjective impression is, that crucial plugins were never affected by this kind of problem and with Trac that happened a bit fewer.

Last Last but not least least, I will try out [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) as it offers builtin workflow for code review.

Comment: You can add : 1. expression ticket workflow in TRAC is just far more powerful than in RedMine 2. Redmine don't have yet actions displayed as non-coder-human-understandable sentences.

Comment: What do you mean "it has died"?

Comment: I can remember a time where the development was much faster. Also orphan plugins are a major problem to Trac. (Of course redmine will also have this problem) So there is still development but at a much lower level. This is my personal point of view.

Comment: +1 installation of RM is not easy, notice that the GIT -repo in Github is unstable development -repo! Wasted hours with it and then realized that the software was buggy...the devs are less interested to keep the master working like gitolite -devs so download the tar -balls. No make -file so slow and painful probably to upgrade and maintain later, just a guess.

Comment: +1 here. Installing Redmine is so shitty. The manual never details the dependencies clearly. In the final step, you realize it just can't be integrated well with apache.

Comment: @hhh: Well, actually, this is the point of a SCM. Unless you want to work on Redmine, you are not supposed to use the last HEAD revision. Use a tag or download a tarball.

Comment: Love python so much,I've tried times to turn to Trac from Redmine in the past 7 years. Lack of native multiprojects support is the 1st reason blocking me. It's a shame for a good FOSS no seriously considering on a big feature for so long a time, especially when there is an excellent reference. Redmine installation sucks, but I, who take it as a long-term infrastructure for the whole company, don't care, since that's just onetime job. Not only a feature, but multiproject also will significantly ease your provision, backup, SLA management etc if you have many(say 50+) projects. So hurry up,Trac.

Comment: @John Wang: Have you ever read my answer? Multiproject support will _NOT_ ease backup! `for i in *; do trac-admin hotcopy $i $i.backup.tgz; done` is much easier than the backup routines from Redmine! What if you want to restore only one project, and leave the others?, consider database management? really? And installation is not a one time job when you really care about security updates. So Trac, please leave it as it is! Its very convenient.

Comment: Time changes many things. Any changes regarding this comparison after 4 years on 2015, June?

Comment: Yes, indeed, many issue tracker are now SaaS. A very nice ranking site is: https://project-management.zone/ranking But still Trac and Redmine are one of the most successful Open Source systems where you have the full control.

Comment: Did I mentioned Gitlab anywhere?

Answer (score 18):

At BitNami we provide free installers and VMs for [Trac](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac) and [Redmine](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine). Redmine is definitely much more popular but Trac is getting more popular, in particular as 1.0 version is around the corner. Since you mentioned Git or DVCS support, you may also be interested in [Gitorious](http://bitnami.org/stack/gitorious) or [Gitlab](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab)

Comment: I've tested the bitnami ubuntu VMWare image: It worked out of the box and we are happy with it

Comment: @Daniel Lopez: At Bitnami, you use MySQL (i dont' want it) and Apache (our admin doesn't want it). As a complete Ruby noob, it took me two days to figure out how to install Redmine on Windows with IIS and MS-SQL (our admin doesn't want to setup pg/mysql, because he wants ONE backup with MS). However, the Linux VM is really nice, learnt something there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working very much with redmine, and I love it!

1. **svn and/or dcvs (Git) support**

   got it both. if you add the ticket number to the commit message, the commit will appear very elegant in the ticket, this is one of my favorite features as developer :)
2. **document management**

   got it too, but just very minimalism. You can upload files to tickets and projects (seperately) but you can't search for them (i.e.)
3. **ticketing, bug tracking, wiki**

   yes, yes and... yes :) I like the syntax of writing tickets or other text contents, kind of similar with the syntax at stackoverflow.com.
4. **multiple project support**

   of cause you can create projects, sub-projects, sub-sub-projects.... with different access rights if necessary. You can also do this cascading with tickets.
5. **installation and plugins**

   I have never installed a redmine instance, and I have no experience with ruby. I'm just a redmine user - but I know that it is possible to write own extensions (my company has written one for own purposes, to extend the tracking of time)

**Conclusion:** I will always use Redmine when I need a ticket system!

**Update:** Sometimes I am also using the issue integration of code hosters like bitbucket or github. Redmine is the largest solution I've used. Trello is also an alternative, which I like to use to handle customer tasks (you can create teams), when not much people are involved and the project is not that big.

Answer (score 3):

Redmine has all that out of the box in a generally very good quality.

However the Installation of Redmine is a different issue. Redmine has a lot of dependencies and many of those dependencies have multiple versions which are not compatible with each other. I was unable to install the most recent redmine manually so far.

What worked fine however was the redmine package provided by Debian Squeeze. It's an older version (1.0.1-2) but has everything you need. I know that openSUSE and Ubuntu also provide redmine packages. (both version 1.1.3, they weren't able to get an recent version installed either, huh?)

Comment: I've tested the debian package and its broken. Varying data is managed under /usr/share not under /var that is a no go. Also some directories are not created needed by the plugin infrastructure. You may see this in with some plugins when you employ Page-Speed with Firebug.

Answer (score 3):

We have been using Redmine for some time. It may have been difficult to install in the past (I didn't think so) but Ubuntu now includes it so installing is a simple one liner "apt-get install red mine". Then you just turn on the passenger module "a2enmod passenger" and finally enable the redmine site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with either Trac, or Redmine, we use Gemini, but you can find a comparison of project management tools [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software).

Hope this helps, 
Dave

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the link but I already found it a couple of days ago. Moreover, there was a deletion discussion about this wikipedia article because the comparison table was/is supposed to not be up-to-date (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Comparison_of_project_management_software). So I cannot verify whether their infos on Trac and Redmine are correct or not.

Comment: ok, apologies, didn't realise there was a deletion discussion around this. Although I can't comment directly on Trac or Redmine I can say that Redmine does seem to be the more popular system based on frequency of recommendations I've seen for it on stackoverflow. Am sure someone will have a more suitable answer though - hope you get the info you need.