# codendi vs redmine vs Retrospectiva vs trac

Tags: project-management, comparison, trac, redmine, retrospectiva

Has anyone tried [codendi](http://codendi.com/), [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), [Retrospectiva](http://retrospectiva.org/) and [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) ? or anyone is able to make some comparison between the four? whichone better related:

- performance
- easy to use
- installation
- and others

and which better Operating System to implement each of those application ?

many thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried coded or Retrospectiva but I've used both redmine and trac, and in my opinion, redmine is better because:

- Easier installation for multiple projects
- Out of the box support for git and mercurial
- support for remote repositories
- support for LDAP authentication
- built in web based administration
- many good plugins available
- and a better looking default theme if you care about that

Initially I was more familiar with python than ruby, so I tended towards trac the first time. But redmine is much more powerful, with more features out of the box, and with a greater community of plugins available.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't tried codendi as well as Retrospectiva, but I've used Trac and Redmine, for long. I would favor Trac over Redmine. A more detailed comparison is given here: [Trac vs. Redmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881578/trac-vs-redmine)

Condendi project pages is saying 100% Open Source, but its not inside of offical Debian / Ubuntu repositories. So either they didn't have packaged it or there are license/legal issues with their interpretation of Open Source to the Debian Open Source style. Its hard tell. Also Retrospectiva is not inside the Debian and Ubuntu Repositories. So I would not even try them.